# Round Robin CPU scheduling algorithm

Tags: c++

I'm kind of lost on how to complete my task for a class that I'm in. The task for this project is to simulate the round robin CPU scheduling with time quantum = 5ms algorithm using an input file containing jobs for CPU. Make sure you implement the waiting queue and ready queue as well.

Project Details:

Part 1:

Input:

Job.txt is provided as input file. Each line contains the name of the job, requesting time (millisecond since computer started) and duration (millisecond). For example:

0,0,80
means a job for CPU called with ID 0,  arrived at CPU at 0ms since CPU started, and the duration of the job is 80ms. Another example:
12,5,45
Means a job with ID 12, arrived at CPU at 5ms since CPU started, and the duration of the job is 45ms.

Output:

Schedule job order similar to the following format

```
$>Job 1, scheduled for 5ms
$>Job 2, scheduled for 5ms
$>Job 1, scheduled for 5ms
$>Job 3, scheduled for 5ms
$>Job 2, scheduled for 3ms, completed
$>job 1, scheduled for 2ms, completed
```

Because round robin is deterministic, you should see the same job scheduling result every time you run your code.

Part 2:
After you simulated the job scheduling for 1 CPU, do the same simulation for 4 CPU assuming you have 4 separate ready Queue and 1 common waiting Queue. What this means is that all jobs waiting will be put into one common queue, and the jobs ready to run will have 4 different queues to put onto.

Here is what I have so far but it isn't working correctly. I"m getting an endless loop and its not loading the information from the input file correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//function to find the waiting time for all the processes
void waitingTime(int processess[], int number, int burstTime[], int waitTime[], int quantum)
{
    //copy of the burst times burstTime[] and to store the remaining time
    int remaining_burstTime[number];
    for (int i=0; i<number; i++)
        remaining_burstTime[i] = burstTime[i];
        
    int time = 0; //current time
    
    //this section will keep going through the processes until they are all done
    while (1)
    {
        bool done = true;
        
        //Go through all processes one by one
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++)
        {
            //if the burst time of the process is greater than 0 then need to run the process further
            if(remaining_burstTime[i]>0)
            {
                done = false; //There is still a pending process
                
                if(remaining_burstTime[i] > quantum)
                {
                    //increase the value of time and shows how much time a process has been processing
                    time += quantum;
                    
                    //decrease the burst_time of the current process by the quantum
                    remaining_burstTime[i] -= quantum; 
                }
                
                //If the burst time is smaller or equal to the quantum.
                else
                {
                    //Increae the value of time and shows how much time the process has been processing
                    time = time + remaining_burstTime[i];
                    
                    //waiting time is current time minus the time used by the process
                    waitTime[i] = time - burstTime[i];
                    
                    //as the process is fully executed the remaining bust time will be =0
                    remaining_burstTime[i] =0;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        //if all the processes are done
        if(done == true)
        break;
    }
}


//function to calculate the turn around time
void find_turnAroundTime(int processes[], int number, int burstTime[], int waitTime[], int turnAroundTime[])
{
    //calculating the turnaround time by adding the burstTime and waitTime
    for (int i =0; i<number; i++)
        turnAroundTime[i] = burstTime[i] + waitTime[i];
}

//function to calculate the average time
void averageTime (int processes[], int number, int burstTime[], int quantum)
{
    int waitTime[number], turnAroundTime[number], total_waitTime=0, total_turnAroundTime=0;
    
    //function to find the wait time for all processes
    waitingTime(processes, number, burstTime, waitTime, quantum);
    
    //function to find the turn around time for all processes
    find_turnAroundTime(processes, number, burstTime, waitTime, turnAroundTime);
    
    //Print the details for the processes
    cout << "Processes" << "Burst Time" << "Waiting time" << "Turn around time\n" <<endl;
    
    //calculate the total waiting and turn around time
    for (int i=0; i<number; i++)
    {
        total_waitTime = total_waitTime + waitTime[i];
        total_turnAroundTime = total_turnAroundTime + turnAroundTime[i];
        cout << " " << i+1 << "\t\t" << burstTime[i] << "\t" << waitTime[i] << "\t\t" << turnAroundTime[i] << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Average waiting time: " << (float)total_waitTime / (float)number;
    cout << "\nAverage turn around time: " << (float)total_turnAroundTime / (float)number;
}

int main()
{
    //process id's
        int id=0;
    int processes[]={id};

    int number = sizeof processes / sizeof processes[0];
    
    //burst time of the processes
    int burst_time[]={id};
    
    
    //quantum time
    int quantum = 5;
    
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("job.txt");
    
    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            inputFile >> processes[i], burst_time[i];
            id++;
            averageTime(processes, number, burst_time, quantum);
            
        }

            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `processes` is an array with a single element, `number` is therefore 1 and your program has undefined behaviour when you try to write to `processes[1]`. Try using `std::vector` if you want a growing array

Comment: I tried making a vector but I don't think I did it correctly because it cant get it to work.